# After moving site to localhost links no longer work with clean urls enabled

Tags: drupal, mamp

CiviCRM 4.7.7 and Drupal 7.43 installation on MAMP stack on Mac. I downloaded the files and database from a live site to verify that the backup worked. The home page comes up fine but clicking on any links brings up a generic MAMP page:

[image: generic MAMP message]

When I turn off clean urls the links work properly. The links on the live site work fine with clean urls enabled.

Answer (score 1):

After commenting out the line "RewriteBase /" in the .htaccess file, clean urls worked as expected.